# Services.AddOptions() ambiguous

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, project.json

I am busy migrating our ASP.NET Core API from RC1 to RC2.

RC2 requires that [we configure the following](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) when using `IOptions<T>`:

```
services.AddOptions();
```

But I get the following compilation error:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.AddOptions(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'
>   and
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions.AddOptions(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)' TransitApi.Api..NET
>   Framework 4.5.2

These are the exact same extension methods! I have tried deleting all packages and deleting the lock files, but to no avail.

The project.json:

```
{
  "title": "MyProject.Api",
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {

    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": { }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't put **tags** into Question Title. We spend much time fixing this all the day and have less time for answering questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging And don't use wrong tags neither. ASP.NET is for the legacy ASP.NET 4.5, **not** for ASP.NET Core

Comment: I can't replicate this, running `dotnet restore` and then `dotnet build` on what you showed works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your dependencies under "References" within the project.

One of your dependencies is fetching old libraries, I suspect it's `"WindowsAzure.Storage": "7.0.0"` as it seems the only candidate for it. I think the [`7.0.2` preview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net) version is ready for `rc2-final` according to GitHub project page, try this please.

Comment: It wasn't exactly `WindowsAzure.Storage`, but it was another library referenced in another project which was not RC2-ready. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you know? How can I detect which one is the responsible?

Comment: @davenewza how did you figure out which reference it was? What was the reference? I am in a very similar situation right now.

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't directly your issue (I suspect @Tseng has correctly identified the dependency issue), you can probably safely omit the call to `AddOptions()`.

The `WebHostBuilder` class implicitly calls `AddOptions` within the call to `Build()`, as can be seen in [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/db4b0af98b659c88efdd8b1285d35d2c3790ab4c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L195). Assuming you are building your web app in the usual way, `AddOptions` will already be registered on the service collection

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/591) for additional information on how a reference to the older version for RC1 is most likely the issue.